# Assistance with simple trigger in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I've googled and tried my best but no luck.

Need to set a column to either m.jpg or f.jpg depending on the submited sex field.

I am using phpmyadmin and created a AFTER Insert trigger

IF NEW.m_sex LIKE 'male' THEN 
UPDATE Members SET NEW.m_photo = 'm.jpg' ELSE IF NEW.m_sex LIKE 'female' THEN UPDATE Members SET NEW.m_photo = 'f.jpg';

Tried many variation get syntax error every time.

thanks

Comment: Please add your full trigger code (including delimiters)

Comment: Every sql statement needs to be terminated - your first update isn't and else if should be elseif. It's impossible to say if these are the only errors without seeing the rest of the trigger, its also possible that you have not provided an endif and that you are attempting to update the table which fired the trigger.

Comment: I added screen shots here https://ibb.co/B2msm9H
https://ibb.co/cCVHT8g  Yes it's the same table. Can't that be done? I have other ways just wanted to try triggers.

Comment: 'Yes it's the same table. Can't that be done' - no it cannot. You are allowed to adjust NEW. values in a before trigger if that helps..